# how to implement Swipe view in mobile using javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, swipeview

I am implementing a project in Phonegap-android.i would like to add a **SWIPE VIEW** for the length of the data available in the database.

Please guide how to implement the swipe view using java script similar to the one in android.

I have tried out with many but was not successful.. i have tried it with **hammer.js,iscroll.js,Swipeview.js,idangerous Swiper.js.**

For, the last two i.e **Swipeview.js,idangerous Swiper.js**,i had an android bug

```
Miss a drag as we are waiting for WebCore's response for touch down.
```

I tried fixing it with the code

```
document.addEventListener( 'touchstart', function(e){ onStart(e); }, false );
function onStart ( touchEvent ) {
  if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) ) {
    touchEvent.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

inspite of this code i faced the same WARNING.
Whereas with **hammer.js,iscroll.js** it did not execute properply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following links which will guide you for swipe view:

1. [iscroll-4](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4)
2. [swipejs](http://swipejs.com/)
3. http://cubiq.org/swipeview

Comment: MIss poo,thats done...if you notice you have to give the number of slides you want.I have implemnted it from [SWIPER](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/) in this i have implemented the threshold type. **I am facing 2 problems.** **one** is if i want **5** slides i need to mention **6** slides in the HTML. **other** is if i 5 types of categories and in this 5 categories not all the categories will have same number of slides.this why i am trying to use the **HIDE** property.which i could not.

Comment: @user I don't have the idea about the android as I am developer of PHP but hope above given link will help you and if you have any issue in JS then I can help you.

Comment: @ MIss poo,it is not in android,all the coding is done in JS,HTML

Comment: @user ok, well I have used this library before. I need time to explore it. and I will give you after analysis that where is the problem.